# How to switch activities using spinner

Tags: java, android, navigation, spinner

How do I create a spinner that gives out three option and on choosing one, corresponding activity opens after clicking a "continue" button.

Comment: What you tired till?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add 3 values in list and set it to your spinner using adapter.
And on button click check spinner selected value. In short if spinner selected = A then go to A else if B else C